# Issue in redirection with LinkContainer with NavItem in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I am a newbie to react. I am trying to redirect via a bootstrap navigation bar. My navbar code looks like the following

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../action_creators';

class MainNav extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         loggedIn: 1,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
               <div>
                <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <a href="/">Test NavBar</a>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Collapse>
                        <Nav>
                            <LinkContainer to={`/test1`}>
                                <NavItem onClick={this.props.getTestContent1} eventKey={1}>Test1</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to = {`/test2`}>
                               <NavItem onClick={this.props.getTestContent2} eventKey={2}>Test2</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
                <div className="content">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

MainNav.propTypes = {
  getTestContent1 : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getTestContent2 : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null,actionCreators)(MainNav);
```

As you can see each Nav item has an onclick event attached to it which is done to fetch data from the server which for which i am using redux-thunk. I have no issue in that part. The main issue I am facing is redirection is not happening. My routes file looks like the following

```
import MainNav from './components/navbar.jsx';
import {HomePageContainer} from './components/defaultHome.jsx';
import testHomePageContainer from './components/testHomePage.jsx';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Route,Switch  } from 'react-router-dom';

export const routes2 =
    <MainNav>
        <Switch>
            <Route  exact path="/" component={HomePageContainer}/>
            <Route  path="/test1" component={testHomePageContainer}/>
            <Route  path="/test2" component={testHomePageContainer}/>
        </Switch>
</MainNav>
```

So when i click on test1 i am still on homepage container and testHomePageContainer is not getting rendered.
I am not sure what is preventing the redirection. thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: hi what your react and React Version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Your React and All other Version but You can get help with update React version :

```
"history": "^4.6.3",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-router": "^4.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
"webpack": "^3.3.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
```

**React Rout** Look LIke it...

```
 import {BrowserRouter,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom'; // for BrowserRouter rout

<BrowserRouter>
       <div>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Layout}></Route>
          <Route path='/test1' name="test1" component={testHomePageContainer}> </Route>
           <Route path='/test2' name="test2" component={Nametest}></Route>
       </div>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

More details about New [**React Rout Quick Start**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router)

For **Link** View or nav View

```
    <Link to="/test1">Check rout link test1</Link>
     <Link to="/test2">Check rout link test2</Link>
```

Comment: Thank for your response. I am using React-router v4 and wanted to use Linkcontainer provided by 'react-router-bootstrap' because using link was making my navigation bar look a bit odd

Comment: SO just change my answer  `Link` to `Linkcontainer ` I hope ...problem solve by this..

Comment: Yes. It did work. I also had an issue with my components import which was the main reason why the component wouldn't load. I realized that the variable name that I set to export was different from the one I import in routes.

Comment: No. The issue was fixed. As i said it was because of the import statement. I imported a different variable from the component than what was actually required. Thanks